# X axis glitch Fl_charts

Tags: flutter, dart, graph, fl-chart

I have data in the form of [DateTime, num]. I have converted the DateTime object into a string and used it as a x-axis label. I am getting this glitch now. Is there a property which I need to change to fix this?[image]

As you can see, there is a repetition of the x axis labels at either end. I am using Fl_Chart library. If you require my current code I can attach it.

Comment: i am having this issue myself, did you find the issue

Answer (score 0):

fl_chart uses the interval you provide to determine which points should have labels for, however, it also creates a label for 0 and maxX. You can fix it by adding

```
if (value % (xAxisInterval?.ceil() ?? 1) == 0) {
   //return label
}else{
   return SideTitleWidget(
                  axisSide: meta.axisSide,
                  child: Container(),
                );    
}
```

to your getTitlesWidget function. Where xAxisInterval is the value you passed into your SideTitles object for interval for the xAxis.